# How to target border-bottom-left-radius using Salesforce Styling Hooks?

Tags: css, slds-styling-hooks

I'm trying to target the input box ".slds-input" in the Salesforce lightning-input component.
What is the correct syntax for border-bottom-left-radius using Salesforce Styling Hooks?

I've tried:

```css
.custom-input{
    --slds-c-input-radius-border-bottom-left: 0px;
}
```

However this didn't work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide all four radiuses in this Styling Hook `--slds-c-input-radius-border` as below.

*CSS*

```
.....
.....
.custom-border {
    --slds-c-input-radius-border:10px 20px 30px 40px;
    --slds-c-input-color-background:green;
}
.....
.....
```

*HTML*

```
.....
.....
<lightning-card>
    <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter some text" class="slds-p-around_medium custom-border"></lightning-input>
</lightning-card>
.....
.....
```

[image]